# Не работает анимация

Tags: c#, opengl

Всем привет, имеется программа, которая моделирует небольшой спутник и необходимо, чтобы была анимация вращения этого спутника по трем осям. Но при попытке написания анимации возникает проблема при компиляции: программа попросту закрывается. Как бороться с этим?
upd: урезал код, чтоб не читать много, от этого не изменилась проблема хД

```
        public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AnT1.InitializeContexts();
        Glut.glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
        Glut.glutMainLoop();

    }

    private void AnT1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // инициализация Glut 
        Glut.glutInit();
        Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_RGB | Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH);

        // очитка окна 
        Gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);

        // установка порта вывода в соотвествии с размерами элемента anT 
        Gl.glViewport(0, 0, AnT1.Width, AnT1.Height);

        // настройка проекции 
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Glu.gluPerspective(45, (float)AnT1.Width / (float)AnT1.Height, 0.1, 200);
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // настройка параметров OpenGL для визуализации 
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Draw();
        Glut.glutSwapBuffers();
        Glut.glutPostRedisplay();
        Gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
    void Draw()
    {
        //основание
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Gl.glColor3f(0.502f, 0.502f, 0.502f);

        Gl.glTranslated(-1, 0, -6);
        Gl.glRotated(95, 1, 0, 0);
        Glut.glutSolidCylinder(0.7, 2, 60, 60);

    }
```

Comment: ну, увы, повторяющиеся строчки необходимы, т.к. у меня по сути аппарат состоит из цилиндров. а каков смысл разбивать все это на отдельные методы?

Comment: >т.к. у меня по сути аппарат состоит из цилиндров.

как это отрицает полезность базового рефакторинга?

Comment: хм, такие понятия, я, увы, не знаю /: а рефакторинг подразумевает различные положения моих поверхностей? вообще, мне науч рук говорил, что тебе поставлена задача, решай как хочешь, хоть самыми тупыми способами, ибо мы не профессиональные программисты. так что мне не столь пока оптимизация важна, сколько работоспособность кода...

Comment: рефакторинг не влияет на работоспособность и оптимизированность кода, однако он способен сделать код проще, понятнее и элегантнее, а следовательно, и упростить поиск ошибок и проблемных мест. У вас есть много строк с повторяющимся кодом. Если выделить этот дублирующийся код в один метод, то он станет в разы короче. Согласитесь, что найти ошибку в десяти строках проще, чем в сотне.

Comment: @mr07th: ну не повезло вам с адекватным научруком, но разве вам не надоело самому копипастить один и тот же код миллион раз?

Comment: > проблема при компиляции  
> программа попросту закрывается

Мне одному тут видится неувязка?

Comment: да, глупость написал, код прекрасно компилится, но после компиляции форма сразу закрывается, не выводя анимацию...так-то надоедало конечно, но на тот момент о рефакторинге просто не знал :) вообще, я так полагаю, что в инициализации возможно проблема и там либо что-то не дописал, либо имеется ошибка /: вот только понять ее не могу никак

Comment: @mr07th воспользуйтесь отладкой, пройдите пошагово, посмотрите, где ваш код падает, с каким исключением. По указанной вами информации что-то конкретное сказать сложно - совершенно непонятно, что, где и когда падает

Comment: я могу сказать, что у меня начинает падать код в этих местах: в Form3 // Glut.glutDisplayFunc(Draw);  //    Glut.glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, 0);  //    Glut.glutMainLoop(); и в AnT1_Load()    //     Glut.glutSwapBuffers();    //     Glut.glutPostRedisplay();
как раз те операторы, которые отвечают за анимацию /:

Comment: @mr07th еще раз - пройдите под отладчиком и посмотрите, что конкретно у вас там происходит. "лечить по фотографии" мы к сожалению не умеем

Comment: @mr07th: Я конечно не знаток opengl, но код `Glut.glutMainLoop();` в **конструкторе** формы кажется мне очень подозрительным.

Answer (score 1):

```
Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
Gl.glPushMatrix();
Draw(); //старое тело функции
Glut.glutSwapBuffers();
Glut.glutPostRedisplay();
Gl.glPopMatrix();
```

точно нужно внести в Draw, поскольку это вовсе не настройка параметров, а связанные с отрисовкой действия, которые выполняются для каждого кадра: очистка цветового и "глубинного" буфера, сохранение модельно-видовой матрицы, собственно отрисовка, выведение изображения на экран, команда на повторную отрисовку и наконец возврат к ранее сохраненной модельно-видовой матрице.